# Get all numbers from string c++

Tags: c++, string, integer

I know this question is asked for several times, but none of the answer fits with my need.
So I have this string

> Sep=1, V_Batt=7.40, I_Batt=-559.63, V_SA=7.20, I_SA=-0.55, I_MB=500.25,  V_5v=4.95, I_5v=446.20, V_3v=3.28, I_3v=3.45, S=0,  T_Batt=25.24, T_SA1=22.95, T_SA2=-4.86

I want to get all of the number after the "=" sign and make a new string like

> 1,7.40,559.63,7.20,0.55,500.25,4.95,446.20,3.28,3.45,0,25.24,22.95,4.68

Can anyone help me to solve the problem. I have used stringstream but I got all 0 for my output 
Thank you

Comment: You're going to need to show your attempt.

Comment: I have used stringstream but I got all 0

Comment: I can't get anything because I'm not telepathic and I can't see your code.

Comment: @Hoa.N show your code.

Answer (score 1):

Based on a corrected understanding of what's actually desired, I'd do things quite differently than I originally suggested. Under the circumstances, I agree with Stephen Webb that a regular expression is probably the right way to go, though I differ as to the right regex to use, and a bit in how to use it (though the latter is probably as much about habits I've formed as anything else).

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using iter = std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::const_iterator>;

    std::string s = "Sep=1, V_Batt=7.40, I_Batt=-559.63, V_SA=7.20,
                    " I_SA=-0.55, I_MB=500.25, V_5v=4.95, I_5v=446.20,"
                    " V_3v=3.28, I_3v=3.45, S=0, T_Batt=25.24, T_SA1=22.95," 
                    " T_SA2=-4.86";

    std::regex re(R"#([A-Z][^=]*=([-\.\d]+))#");

    auto begin = iter(s.begin(), s.end(), re, 1);
    iter end;

    for (auto i = begin; i!= end; ++i)
        std::cout << *i << ", ";
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Result:

1, 7.40, -559.63, 7.20, -0.55, 500.25, 4.95, 446.20, 3.28, 3.45, 0, 25.24, 22.95, -4.86,

Comment: Yes, I want to get the values after the "equals" sign only, I have found a way using a regex but then I don't know how to discards some numbers I don't want in the string

Answer (score 0):

If the number of arguments and their order are known, you can use [snprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/) like this:

```
char str[100];
int Sep=1;
double V_Batt = 7.40, I_Batt = 559.63;// etc ...
snprintf(str, 100, "%d,%.2f,%.2f", Sep, V_Batt, I_Batt); //etc...
// str = 1,7.40,559.63
```

Answer (score 0):

Open your file with fopen() function.
It returns you the File* variable. Of course, if already available your chars, just skip this step.
Use this File variable to get each char, let's say, by means of fgetc().
Check the content of obtained char variable and make what you want with it, eventually insert some comma in your new string, as necessary

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what `std::regex_iterator` is for.

```
#include <regex>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    const std::string s = "Sep=1, V_Batt=7.40, I_Batt=-559.63, V_SA=7.20, I_SA=-0.55, I_MB=500.25, V_5v=4.95, I_5v=446.20, V_3v=3.28, I_3v=3.45, S=0, T_Batt=25.24, T_SA1=22.95, T_SA2=-4.86";
    std::regex re("[-\\d\\.]+");
    auto words_begin = std::sregex_iterator(s.begin(), s.end(), re);
    auto words_end = std::sregex_iterator();

    for (std::sregex_iterator i = words_begin; i != words_end; ++i)
        std::cout << (*i).str() << ',';
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

The output of the above complete program is this.

> 1,7.40,-559.63,7.20,-0.55,500.25,5,4.95,5,446.20,3,3.28,3,3.45,0,25.24,1,22.95,2,-4.86,